# Regex to remove string inside an URL

Tags: php, regex

I have a URL where I pass the base auth within the URL, example:

```
https://user:pass@dev.google.com
```

What would be a regex to remove everything between the last **/** up to the **@**?

Example:

```
https://user:pass@dev.google.com
```

Would become:

```
https://dev.google.com
```

I tried some regex but my knowledge is still basic for this subject.

I'll use a PHP function to do a replace.

Comment: Which programming language? Do not comment, just add a proper tag.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a regexp instead of `parse_url()`?

Comment: @Barmar no reason at all, I'm actually new to php so I'm not familiar with `parse_url()` yet, I'll take a look on this, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('#/[^/]*@#', '/', $url);
```

Breakdown:

- `/` matches a slash
- `[^/]*` matches a sequence of non-slash characters
- `@` matches the `@` character.

So this matches everything from a `/` to the next `@`, with no `/` between them. Then it's replaced with just the slash.

However, it would probably be better to use `parse_url()` rather than ad hoc parsing with a regexp.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem, I'll accept the answer as soon as it let me :)

Comment: And what about url's like `example.com/@username/profile`?

Comment: @Philipp That's why I recommended using a URL parser rather than ad hoc parsing, since it will deal with corner cases better.

Answer (score 1):

Using `parse_url()` does the job:

```
$url = 'https://user:pass@dev.google.com';
$scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
print $scheme."://".$host;
```